# how to adjust this algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I have an algorithm and I would like to adjust it to look good. I have some matrices and some equations, so I would like to put the text in the left not in the center.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
  \caption{title}

  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \For  {all } 
    \State{ 
     \begin{equation*}
        \begin{bmatrix}
         a \\
         a \\
         a \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        =
        \begin{bmatrix}
         b \\
         b \\
         b \\
        \end{bmatrix}
     \end{equation*}
     \For {aaaa}
     \State{
       \begin{align*}
            \delta_{p} &= 
            \begin{bmatrix}
            e \\
            e 
            \end{bmatrix} \\
            W &= W      \\      
            S &= S \\
            D &= D
        \end{align*}
     }
     \EndFor
     \State{
    \begin{align*}
    a &=a \\
    a &= a
    \end{align*}         
 }
    } 
    \EndFor 


  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Also, I'm using `align` which increases the vertical space between lines. Is there any way to decrease the vertical space?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one attempt:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
  \caption{title}

  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \setlength{\lineskip}{3pt}
    \For  {all }
    \State{
     $
        \begin{bmatrix}
         a \\
         a \\
         a \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        =
        \begin{bmatrix}
         b \\
         b \\
         b \\
        \end{bmatrix}
     $
     \For {aaaa}
     \State{
       $\begin{aligned}[t]
            \delta_{p} &=
            \begin{bmatrix}
            e \\
            e
            \end{bmatrix} \\
            W &= W      \\
            S &= S \\
            D &= D
          \end{aligned}
        $
     }
     \EndFor
     \State{
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
    a &=a \\
    a &= a
    \end{aligned}
    $
 }
    }
    \EndFor


  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You get a better result if you increase `\lineskip` in the `algorithm` environment; try with `\setlength{\lineskip}{3pt}` just before the first `\For` to see what I mean.

Comment: @egreg Thanks and I updated the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: The big in line objects cause `\lineskip` glue instead of the normal `\baselineskip` glue, because this would result negative. The default value is 1pt, but in a case like this, giving more room seems better. The effect is clearly seen between lines 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4.